# Inequality involving sum of fractions

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an inequality involving sums of fractions.
In particular I'm looking for the inequality

$$ \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{p_k}{q_k} \geq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n p_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n q_k } $$
for positive values $p_i, q_i > 0$.

All examples that I tried, fulfilled the inequality, hence my question:

Does this inequality hold or is there an example that disproves it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Take $p_2=...=p_n\rightarrow0$.

We need to prove that:
$$q_1+q_2+...+q_n\geq nq_1.$$ Now take  $q_1\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: Yep, you're right ($p_1 = 1$).
An explicit counterexample would be $1/2 (5/3 + 3/2) = 19/12$ which is strictly smaller than $(5+3)/(3+2)=19.2/12$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2$ we get
$$(q_2p_1-q_1p_2)(q_2-q_1)\geq 0$$
Why should this be?